# Multilevel option in select HTML

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am currently developing a website and I have a problem.
I want to make a list with several levels (hierarchical), except that apparently it doesn't exist (if yes tell me).
So I made myself a system with invisible characters, the problem is that once selected, the tabs remain and it prevents to see correctly what is written. Do you have a solution?

Thank you in advance!

The problem : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhl1w.png)

The list when open : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSaKh.png)

The code :

```html
<select name="selectEmp" id="selectEmp" class="form-control selectEmp">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="00.00.00" disabled="disabled">00.00.00 - Total</option>
            <option value="10.00.00" disabled="disabled">10.00.00 - Bâtiment 1</option>
            <option value="10.10.00" disabled="disabled">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10.10.00 - Cave</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="10.10.10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10.10.10 - Test</option>
            <option value="10.20.00" disabled="disabled">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10.20.00 - Niveau 1</option>
            <option value="10.30.00" disabled="disabled">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10.30.00 - Niveau 2</option>
            <option value="20.00.00" disabled="disabled">20.00.00 - Bâtiment 2</option>
            <option value="20.10.00" disabled="disabled">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;20.10.00 - Cave</option>
            <option value="20.20.00" disabled="disabled">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;20.20.00 - Niveau 1</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can able to use optgroup. See below code. Hope, this will help.

```
<select name="selectEmp" id="selectEmp">
      <option value="00.00.00 - Total"></option>
      <optgroup value="10.00.00" label="10.00.00 - Bâtiment 1">
            <option value="1">10.10.00 - Cave</option>
            <option value="2">10.10.10 - Test</option>
            <optgroup value="10.00.00" label="10.10.10 - Test">
                  <option value="2">10.20.00 - Niveau 1</option>
            </optgroup>
            <option value="2">10.30.00 - Niveau 2</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup value="10.00.00" label="20.00.00 - Bâtiment 2">
            <option value="1">20.10.00 - Cave</option>
            <option value="2">20.20.00 - Niveau 1</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because optgroup don't be tabulated
https://i.imgur.com/kU72cZn.png